# I want to reallocate a double switch and also split it into two switches. Can I do it like this? Is it 100% safe?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

As the title says, I want to reallocate a double switch and also split it into two switches. I know this is a very basic question, but I just want to be 200% sure this is safe, as I nearly don't have any experience on playing around with electricity.

The point is to basically split the power cable into two using a connector and two other cables and, of course, plug the bathroom/kitchen cables into their respective new switches. But the drawing should be self explanatory. Also, I live in Europe, thus this is on 220~240V.[image: A rough drawing of the circuit]

Comment: Are you going to mount the new two switches side by side in the same electrical box?

Comment: @MichaelKaras No, the two new switches are going to be screwed outside of the wall (they don't go in the wall) and I will be using the box of the current switch ( that is mounted on the wall) as a junction box and cover it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your original switch box as a junction box, and put a blank cover on it when you're done.

Never make any connections inside the wall where they are not protected, or where they cannot be accessed.

This is common practice here in the US.

Comment: Yes, I'll be doing the connection inside the original switch box and then cover it. Should be 100% safe like that, correct?

Comment: Yes sir, should be safe.